# Ruby run on Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: ruby, macos, capslock

I want ruby to perform an action when the capslock button is pressed. 
On my Mac I installed the program called Sail which changes the capslock keycode to the keycode of F19 (80). Is there now a way to run some ruby code when the capslock button gets pressed?

Comment: Maybe you could glue something together using [Automator and a global hotkey](http://blog.fosketts.net/2010/08/09/assign-keyboard-shortcut-applescript-automator-service/).

Comment: maybe check out my [linux-keyboard-macros](https://github.com/maxpleaner/linux-keyboard-macros) for a little inspiration. It won't work on OSX unless you install `evtest` and `xdotool`, and even then you'd have to add support for capslock. Bascially what I did is find a program which shows a streaming output of all keys pressed, then I captured that stream's output in Ruby, parsed it using Regex, and tracked which "phrases" were typed in order to triger events.